# Searching keywords from one array against values of another array - php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, sorting, strpos

I have 2 arrays. One with bad keywords and the other with names of sites.

```
$bad_keywords = array('google', 
                      'twitter', 
                      'facebook');

$sites = array('youtube.com', 'google.com', 'm.google.co.uk', 'walmart.com', 'thezoo.com', 'etc.com');
```

Simple task: I need to filter through the `$sites` array and filter **out** any value that **contains** any keyword that is found in the `$bad_keywords` array. At the end of it I need an array with clean values that I would not find any bad_keywords occurring at all.

I have scoured the web and can't seem to find a simple easy solution for this. Here are several methods that I have tried:
1. using 2 `foreach` loops (feels slower - I think using in-built php functions will speed it up)
2. [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
3. [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

But I haven't managed to nail down the best, most efficient way. I want to have a tool that will filter through a list of 20k+ sites against a list of keywords that may be up to 1k long, so performance is paramount. Also, what would be the better method for the actual search in this case - `regex` or `strpos`?

What other options are there to do this and what would be the best way?

Comment: what your expected output

Comment: @ArunKumaresh Output: the filtered $sites array (i.e. does not contain any elements that a bad_keyword is found inside it's value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short solution using [***preg_grep***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) function:

```
$result = preg_grep('/'. implode('|', $bad_keywords) .'/', $sites, 1);
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => youtube.com
    [3] => walmart.com
    [4] => thezoo.com
    [5] => etc.com
)
```